# How could I replace a find_package of CMakeList by its installation directory?

Tags: cmake, sfml

I need to install SFML by sources but I can't run cmake because a package is not installed (`xcb-image`)

I installed this packages by sources, but how can I tell CMake that this package is installed, and that it needs to look at a special directory?

```
if(NOT SFML_OPENGL_ES)
    find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
    if(SFML_OS_LINUX OR SFML_OS_FREEBSD)
        find_package(XCB COMPONENTS xlib_xcb image randr REQUIRED)
        if(NOT LIBXCB_FOUND)
            message(FATAL_ERROR "Xcb library not found")
        endif()
        include_directories(${LIBXCB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    endif()
endif()
```

I don't have root access.

Comment: Delete the CMakeCache.txt and pass the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH with the path to you SFTML directory to CMake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding your `xcb` `/include` and `/lib` directory to your CMakeLists, by adding the following lines :

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/path/to/your/xcb/include)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/path/to/your/xcb/lib)
```

Otherwise, if that didn't work and you have a cmake file for cxb (sth like xcb.cmake), Create a folder named cmake/Modules/ under your project root, add `xcb.cmake` under that folder, and in the root CMakeLists.txt, include the following code:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
```

For a better understanding, take a look at [CMake:How To Find Libraries](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries)

Hope that helps !